# Does a field with null divergence in the weak sense satisfy Gauss's theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-fields, stokes-theorem, weak-derivatives

Assume that a measurable vector field $D$ of $\mathbf R^3$ satisfy $\nabla\cdot D = 0$ in the weak sense, that is, $$\int D \cdot \nabla \varphi = 0$$
for every test function $\varphi$.
Does this imply that if $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary, we'll have
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} D \cdot {\bf n} \ ds = 0?$$

**Note:** If $D$ is $C^1$, then this holds true because $\int D\cdot \nabla \varphi = \int (\nabla \cdot D) \ \varphi = 0$ for every test function $\varphi$ implies $\nabla\cdot D = 0$.

Comment: What regularity is $D$? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I assumed nothing more than $D$ measurable. My thoughts are related to physics, $D$ being the displacement fields. I would like to know if the weak formulation of the Maxwell laws in empty space implies the integral form.